# WCF port not listening

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

### Update

The service is running and has a pid in Task Manager but when I run `netstat -ano | find pid#` nothing is returned - the port is not listening.

Also if I run `netstat -ap tcp` the port is not listed.

I really don't know how to fix this. In summary so you don't have to read my previous post:

- My WCF Service works perfectly under localhost (ie service and client on same server)
- When I publish the Service to a production server, the service installs fine but the 8523 port does not listen
- There are several similar posts that I have reviewed but none work for me
- This is my first WCF project that I have attempted so I have exhausted my knowledge and I can't find any more examples on the Internet to try
- At this point I will be very grateful for any pointers

### environment

- development: Windows 7
- Visual Studio: 2015
- production server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- IIS version 7.5.7600.16385

### Introduction

I have researched this issue for a few days now and although I have found a number of similar questions on Stack Overflow, none of those questions solve my problem; therefore I don't think this is a duplicate and it will be specifically helpful if someone is trying to follow the referenced Microsoft tutorial as I have done

### Problem details

I have followed this Microsoft article "How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx.

After creating the solution, it runs perfectly on my development machine within the Visual Studio localhost environment. The tutorial suggests that you create a Test Client to access the WCF solution and that Test client works successfully

When I publish the WCF Service and the Windows Service in the production machine (Windows Server 2008) it again installs without error. Here are the steps that I follow:

*IIS Setup*

- add net.tcp to the enabled protocols
- activate 'Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation'
- Changed bindings for net.tcp to 8532
- Ensure 'Net.Tcp Listener Adapter' is running

*Open 8532 port in firewall*

*Browse to the bin directory of the project where WindowsService1.exe is located and run the exe as administrator*

*Open command Prompt as administrator and run Installutil WindowsService1.exe*

### Differences between Localhost (development environment in Visual Studio) and Production environment

The only changes between the localhost WCF system and production system is I changed the baseAddress in app.conf from

- "net.tcp://localhost:8523/CustomWCFService"

to

- "net.tcp://10.2.1.1:8523/CustomWCFService"

Here is the deployed app.conf

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyCustomServiceLib.CustomServiceLib">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="MyCustomServiceLib.ICustomServiceLib">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://10.2.1.1:8523/CustomWCF" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

### Adding Service Reference

When I try to add the service reference in my application that will use the WCF service. I get this error:

> There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please
>   verify that you have entered a valid address

When I click on "Details" I see this:

> The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://10.2.1.1:8523/CustomWCF'. Could not
>   connect to net.tcp://10.2.1.1:8523/CustomWCF. The connection attempt
>   lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0312368. TCP error code 10061: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 10.2.1.1:8523.  No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it 10.2.1.1:8523 If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

### What I have tried

A lot of the other WCF questions asked on forums seem to be in regards to getting the service working in localhost which does not apply to me because the solution I've created works perfectly in the development environment.

Some of the answers suggest enabling tcp port sharing in the project but when I try and add this code in my solution I get an error saying "not allowed".

Other questions suggest that the url must be registered on the production server but that has no effect.

After trying all the forum suggestions that I can find and trying to correct everything that I think is wrong, I've still have no luck.

Any suggestions or pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: One important point I forgot to mention is when I run netstat -ona | find "8523" nothing is returned. If the port is not listening then the service won't work

Answer (score 0):

I have not gotten WCF to work well with the configuration file in the past.  I have always created the bindings in code.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/DavidBasarab/99d2064f70588309ab1b64df280a01e4) does work.

The important parts are NetTcpBinding

```
 netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
                            {
                                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                                Security = new NetTcpSecurity
                                           {
                                               Mode = SecurityMode.None,
                                               Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
                                           }
                            };
```

Also I would not specify an IP but rather let WCF bind it to every IP Address on the machine.

```
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), netTcpBinding, string.Format("{1}://0.0.0.0:{0}/", port, "net.tcp"));
```

This does not prevent you putting in a specific IP, I just typically do not.

If you want to run it in IIS you have to do a little bit more work.  IIS doesn't really want you to host a WCF server that is not bound in by http.

You have to do a little extra work after creating the ServiceHost

```
 var serviceBehavior = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

if (serviceBehavior == null) return;

serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = false;
serviceBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Agreed, WCF and config files was flaky to me too so I now avoid them for WCF Services.

Comment: David: Thank you so much for the new direction. It is very much appreciated. I will add your suggestions to my code and give it a try

Comment: David: I created a new WCF Library service using your suggested code changes and everything builds without error. However, I do have a question. In order to add a service reference to connect to our new WCF library from another machine, we still need a Windows service to host the WCF service library, correct? Part of building a windows service is providing it with a copy of the app.conf from the WCF Library. We don't have an app.conf file in the library now as it was replaced by your additional programing code. How does the Windows service work without this app.conf file?

Comment: @DrakesDR for WCF you can host it in any exe you want.  It all depends on your application.  A window service is a fine way to consume.  In the past I have had 1 library with all the WCF code.  I had a client and a server.  Then I would just create a new client talking to the server.  There is a BIG WCF gotcha that will trip you up.  You need to make sure you are always using the same models.  If they are different you will get serialization errors and many times WCF will swallow those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this post to detail the results of adding David Basarab suggested changes to my WCF Service Library project. Again many thanks for David's post, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. In fact it didn't even run under localhost in Visual Studio. David mentioned that it worked for him so I probably make a mistake somewhere. Hopefully the details that I provide here will either generate some additional pointers to what I did wrong or help someone else that tries David's approach. I tried to keep the Visual Studio default values when creating the Solution except for David's changes.

### Service Reference Error

Here's the error that I received when I tried to add the Service Reference in my Test Client on the same machine as both the Windows Service and the actual WCF Service Library:

```
The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1'. Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0028015. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523 If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

### WCF Library code

**IService1.cs unit**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    // You can add XSD files into the project. After building the project, you can directly use the data types defined there, with the namespace "CustomServiceLibrary.ContractType".
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Service1.cs code**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomServiceLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.cs class code**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace CustomServiceLibrary
{
    class Server
    {
        private readonly ushort port;
        private readonly Service1 Service1;
        private NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding;
        private ServiceHost serviceHost;

        public Server(ushort port)
        {
            this.port = port;
            Service1 = new Service1();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                CreateServiceHost();

                CreateBinding();

                AddEndpoint();

                serviceHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Service has been opended");

                ConfigureHTTP();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ERROR      := {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"StackTrace := {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }

        private void AddEndpoint()
        {
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), netTcpBinding, string.Format("{1}://0.0.0.0:{0}/", port, "net.tcp"));
        }

        private void ConfigureHTTP()
        {
            var serviceBehavior = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            if (serviceBehavior == null) return;

            serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = false;
            serviceBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
        }

        private void CreateBinding()
        {
            netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                Security = new NetTcpSecurity
                {
                    Mode = SecurityMode.None,
                    Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
                }
            };
        }

        private void CreateServiceHost()
        {
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(Service1);
        }
    }
}
```

### Summary

Other than David's changes that I added to the project, everything else that I did was the same as what I did for the previous deployment using App.conf configuration. I just followed the directions in Microsoft article "How to: Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx